# Azure web api with java

Tags: java, azure, azure-api-apps

[Update: Problem Solved, Clear solution unable to be achieved. More information in comments]

I am new to azure and I am attempting to create a API Application following the tutorial found here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-java-api-app/

Everything works fine on the local machine but when I attempt to push it to the live site and do a Postman request for http://talkapi.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts/2 I get resource not available.

I don't know what bugging tools I have and where to start. I was wondering if anyone had some advice on where to start debugging or what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tuturial and per my experience, it seems that the issue of 404 not found was caused by the incorrect deployment on Azure.

Please access the link `https://talkapi.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` the Kudu tool of your API App and move to the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps`, then you will see the fig below.

[image]

Try to drag your `ROOT.war` file and drop here (`\webapps`), and tomcat will auto-decompress the war file and replace the directory `ROOT`, then you can try to request the api `http://talkapi.azurewebsites.net/api/contacts/2` again.

Kudu is the engine behind git deployments in Azure Web Sites includes Azure API App, you can see more detals at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki.

Hope it helps. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It turns out that the network I was using has some security that was blocking me from uploading a correct version to azure. I used my home network and everything works fine. I am unsure what security they are using that prevents it but I know FTP/Filezilla is blocked. 

Thank you for this way to upload files! I prefer this method.

Comment: I am unable to change the network security settings where I was attempting the initial setup sadly. As such I wasn't able to experiment to find out which settings were causing the problem. I was able to set up everything and have it working from a home network with the same environment though.